# Fixing the cell with 4%PFA and staining with PI to observe cell cycle?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture, cell-cycle, staining, flow-cytometry

I am wondering whether we can replace 70% ethanol to fix and perm the cells with 4% PFA to observe the cell cycle. Do I understand correctly that 4% PFA can permeate the cells, thus the PI will intercalate DNA?

Comment: PFA can also cross-link DNA, interfering with intercalation.

Comment: Thanks, I will search more details.